# Count how many times an android app has been opened for all devices combined

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android App, and I want to know how many times it has been used worldwide. Not how many times it has been installed but rather how often it has been opened.

I read about using persistent storage to count uses per device, but I want to take all of those uses and get the total sum of these values. How could this be done?

Comment: Do you have a web server? Then the app could do a simple web request every time it is started.

Comment: it sounds to me that what u want is: https://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytics API to report about "main screen is opened" event. Aggregation by-days will be performed by analytics itself.

See for details https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#screen-view

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Crashlytics for that, check out http://try.crashlytics.com/answers/

Answer (score 0):

I added a counter in an html page which is presented every time a user opens the app, this is a welcome back screen and shows some news. This sends some code to the server and increments a value in my DB. This value is then presented in Settings, which has a message that says "Sessions since 'date': 'myValue'".

Thanks for all the answers, I might migrate to them if needed.